# Fast lightweight method of detecting skipped values in a cyclic sequence

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, real-time, sequence

I have a single value that, over time, increases from 1 to 6 and then returns to 1. So over several frames the sequence seen would be:

```
1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4...
```

If a hardware device is defective one of those numbers may not read correctly and so the sequence may look like this:

```
1, 2, 6, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 6, 4...
```

**What is a fast, short method of detecting this inconsistency?**

Note:

- This is designed for a **hard real-time** environment
- My current method is to check that each new value every frame has a difference no greater than 1 from the last value, then there is a special case for the difference between 1 and 6 which is allowed to be 5
- I am wondering whether there is a simple algorithm or trick to solving this problem
- The sequence is also valid if it is in reverse, e.g.:
  `6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1, 6, 5, 4, 3....`

Comment: What's wrong with your current approach? Isn't it fast enough? Is it unreliable? Or are you just looking to make things "prettier"?

Comment: Also, if a defect was identified - will you fix it? In other words, when reading the n'th value - can you assume the first n-1 values are all "correct"?

Comment: A simpler approach could possibly be to look at the first value and then we know what the cycle is going to be like. So you would just have to check if the number is equal to the 'predicted' number. If not, you have a cycle break.

Comment: @amit I guess a part of it is making things prettier, the current approach requires a few if statements or one very long if statement. The additional thing I failed to note (I'll update the question) is that the sequence is allowed to go backwards, so you get if statements such as: if current = 1 || current = 6, if difference <= 1 || difference = 5, then everything is okay and this feels clumsy. I' wondering if there's a better method.
Nothing would be fixed if there was a defect, the program would halt and report an error.

Comment: @VivekPradhan would you store the expected values in an array?

Comment: Yeah, you can store the expected values in an array. So if the flow starts with 2. Your expected array could be [2,3,4,5,6,1]. The only thing would be to get back to 2 after the array is exhausted. You could also do away with having an array. So if you start with 2, increment it by 1 after every check. And do a reset to 1 when you cross 6.

Comment: Personally I think the array approach would be better, as the space you are using in terms of memory is also not very huge. And at every check, you're just doing a retrieval and equality test as compared to in the other case where you do an arithmetic operation and an equality test.

Comment: I do like the array approach, and you're right I think it is the fastest, but only if the array doesn't need to be manipulated. You're right in thinking that the sequence could start at any position. With this in mind I'd have to setup the array depending on the first read value.

Comment: Is the sequence allowed to change direction?

Comment: @sydan, that's correct. You'll have to set up the array once based on the first value.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the modulo operator:

```
(current_value - previous_value + 6) mod 6 == 1
```

The `+6` is there to ensure a positive argument to `mod`. Different languages treat negative values differently, but if `-5 mod 6` evaluates to `1` in yours, you can omit the `+6`.

Comment: This looks elegant but I don't see how it could be faster than the proposed solution of the OP.

Comment: @VivekPradhan OP mentions that their approach feels clumsy.

Comment: @JanneKarila, my apologies, this works perfect if the sequence is going forward by not when it is going backward. This is probably my fault because I forgot to mention this when I first wrote the question. I have however noticed that for forward sequences this always == 1 and for backward it always == 5 which might be a good solution. I still need to check it.